# Why is there a shift towards asynchronous and event driven programming?

Tags: multithreading, event-programming, asynchronous-programming

My question will be mostly about Linux and contemporary X86 hardware.

### Clarifying the terms

**async event based programming:** spawning fixed amount of threads and using some user space scheduling mechanism. Usually callbacks are handled in a continuation style, so the callback will be executed in the thread of the consumer, not producer.

**thread, blocking based programming:** using classic OS threads and mutexes and semaphores. Waiting is handled by blocking the calling thread. Although not usually used, in my perspective this requires *cooperative threads* to be effective.

### The status quo from my POV

It seems like more and more people turn away from the classic way of using syncrhonization/cooperation primitives for threading and from blocking (as in making current thread sleep) in general. Their problems seems to be mainly based on the following (italics are my thoughts on the matter):

- Blocking synchronization is prone to deadlocks (*async code can livelock too*)
- Too many threads cause oversubscription and OS scheduler makes latency sky high (*fixable?*)
- Whatever libraries that use threading do not provide any way of cooperation, thus causing the problem above
- High cost of a thread spin-up (*perceived?*)
- Not usable if sleep/wakeup is noticeable compared to active time (*true*)

#5 is not fixable without patching kernel and #3 could be fixed by better teaching.

### The can of worms

Async systems usually rely on events that trigger something else, thus cascading. Even if the above problems were fixed by async event based programming, it creates harder issues that are solvable by blocking thread based programming:

- Starvation (very hard to achieve fairness without OS support, which in turn utilizes hardware clocks to enforce CPU time slices)
- Can break when only one worker is allocated (this is mostly true of lock free queues, nothing can cause progress condition when the worker is not giving CPU time to another task, although this is solved with coroutines)
- Exclusivity and ABA problems (with OS threads no thread can be scheduled on multiple CPUs at the same time, while with event based programming some event might be fired more than needed)
- Complexity either goes into the library (which, if written with poor interface, pretty much doubles the mental complexity) or into the user code

### Why reinvent the wheel?

For most complaints I have seen with thread based blocking programming, I couldn't find any reason why it couldn't be solved with classic approach. The only problem is when a thread needs to run for so small amount of time that typical ~10 microsecond delay will start becoming noticable. It is usually I/O bound applications. On all other cases I found that non-blocking code is usually less efficient on the normal path (non contending), because it does more operations to ensure atomicity. It seems like almost all problems could be solved by using blocking in a better way (don't hold lock for more than very few operations) and exposing parallelism instead of just spawning threads (algorithms could use task queues, for example). Real-time is not possible without preemption, so async event driven code is not real-time by definition. Even the coroutine based frameworks pretty much duplicate the OS scheduler and synchronization primitives.

### Examples when threads are superior

On one occasion I had to utilize only 2 CPU cores for a stream of tasks, where some tasks take about 100 times longer than the others. Having two of those would pretty much stop anything from making progress. I did the following:

1. Allocate two threads for lightweight tasks and make the producers put lightweight tasks into a queue
2. Spin up a thread for every heavy task
3. Put everything under `SCHED_RR` with a timeslice set to upperbound of a lightweight task, so that even in case of heavier tasks, lighter ones could make progress

For async event based programming, this would require support from the callee, and it would have predefined amount of preemption points, while OS based one is a pretty much coroutine with as many preemption points as possible, albeit with less control over where exactly it will be preempted.

### Question

Since async event driven programming offers so little benefits, why is there shift towards it? What am I missing?

Comment: see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)

Comment: When you say 'asynchronous' are you talking about async/await type constructs?

Comment: It's not just in C#.  For example, Python has a similar construct.  The main point of it is to avoid having blocking threads waiting for IO.  Event-driven approaches tend to be used for different reasons (with maybe some overlap.)  I feel like you are mixing two different things here.  Are you primarily asking about event-driven approaches?

Comment: The main (legitimate) motivation for this that threads carry overhead.  They use memory and have context switching costs.  There's a limit on the number of threads you can run efficiently on a given machine.  Therefore, for IO bound applications, you can get a lot more out of your hardware with non-blocking approaches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131469/discussion-between-incomputable-and-jimmyjames).

Comment: I will ask a question later on when I will get the time, please do not delete it until then. Also, if you've got the time, please have a look at the discussion in the chat above for more context. I'm pretty sure there is something interesting about the question that has concrete answers, but I agree that in the current form it might attract too many bad  answers. Lets improve it first before reopening, or put a final nail in it's coffin on meta.

Comment: I think part of the problem with this question is that it conflates asynchrony with threading.  Asynchrony is just a natural feature for any system that relies on some external service (e.g. database, other microservice, etc.), so a program with just one thread can't do anything with that operation until the external service completes.  In the meantime, that thread can either block/sleep or continue doing something else useful asynchronously.   Also remember that many systems these days are split into many microservices and often rely heavily on SaaS/PaaS solutions.

Comment: “Spin up two threads” - GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) uses 64 threads on iOS and 256 threads on MacOS.

Comment: [This article](https://typelevel.org/blog/2021/02/21/fibers-fast-mkay.html) by an author of Scala's biggest async framework has a good explanation.

Comment: surely you are missing the obvious. The async approach is for non-cpu tasks. you dont spin up a new thread because there is no work for the thread to do except wait.

Comment: Downvoting because this isn't a question, it's an argument.  OP already has their answer (async is bad) and simply wants evidence to support it.

Comment: @user949300, that is gigantic overstatement. Async is not bad, just that the effective usage cases are limited to I/O bound apps that is not what I see on regular basis. What I read on the web and even the C++ talks I watched advocate for async. Yet no talk was able to convince me. Nobody shows "here is the place in the kernel that is not possible to go around in userspace/kernelspace and that is why async is better in each and every way". What I saw was "threads are slow, dont use them". My argument that high concurrency is slow, the rest is false perception.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt That article is pretty good but he refers to the "disruptor pattern" which I would assume refers to [this](https://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html) but his description/assertions about it don't seem to align with my understanding of it.

Comment: You are not making the difference between the two perceived paradigms very clear. Nor do I see how this would be bound to Linux or any particular processor family. It may help to provide typical (code) examples and to be a lot more concise, leaving out the essay about your personal assessments. There may or may not be any merit to them, either way they stray from the question. Now you will have people arguing with you over your statements rather than listing reasons.

Answer (score 18):

## The "async" approach better facilitates human reasoning.

When most people drive, they don't need to concern themselves with how every element of the car is interacting. Forget the tires - when you turn the steering wheel, the car turns. Sure, there are exceptional cases where you need to remember that the tires exist, and you need to keep the big picture in your head to avoid big errors. But for the most part, that's background knowledge that won't help you get to the store and back.

### Technology grows to cover the pain points

In computing as a whole, things tend to move from "easy for the machine" to "easy for the person". User-friendliness (noting that developers are the users of programming technologies) is obviously valuable, so as technology and discipline develop, patterns tend toward the human.

In programming languages, for example, we've generally moved from "low" to "high"; machine to assembly to `C` to `C++` to `C#`, for example (not that each is specifically an iteration of its predecessor, but as a general direction). Early languages tended to be more dynamic, because it's easy to interpret a dynamic language, whereas many modern languages tend to come with more compile-time checks and pre-processing. Obviously dynamic and low-level languages are still valuable - especially in specific situations - but the benefits of things like generic types, garbage collection, and syntactic sugar are undeniable for most software development.

### Separate the model from the mechanism

Also look at cloud computing - have you heard the buzzword "serverless"? Obviously there's still a server, but the details of its hardware can be safely ignored in most situations. With architectural patterns like microservices, there's more and more push toward completely isolating different areas of an application domain; each piece is maintained as a black box and coordination is only required at the edges. This is supported and enforced by cloud resources like Azure Functions or AWS Lambda that may not run anywhere near one-another in time and space. Coordinating all of these pieces turns out to be *a distraction* from software design and development rather than a fundamental building block.

This extends naturally to concurrent programming. It's easier to think "pick up here when data is available" than it is to think about scheduling whose turn it is and ensuring that timing works out. Software design principles suggest focusing on a single responsibility, and part of that is keeping the details coordination out of a given chain of events.

Features like `async` and `await` or promise `then` callbacks build upon low-level thread coordination the way loops build on `goto`. They behave in a structured, consistent way that is more limited and with somewhat more overhead, but are ultimately more predictable and quick to use in typical scenarios. When I write `getValue().then(useValue)`, I can assume that code will execute in that order as time progresses, albeit with a time disconnect. Maybe the actual *thread* could run other code in the meantime - why should I care!

Comment: I personally found async (via callbacks) reasonably "logical", because when I first learned systems programming, a long time ago, that what how things were done.  I suspect that my experience is rare: for most other programmers async code is hard for reasoning.  That's why languages have added keywords like `await`, which effectively turn async code into synchronous, for easier reasoning.

Comment: @user949300 I think terms are being used differently all around here. Continuation-like callbacks and keywords `async` and `await` are both what I think the querent describes as "async event based programming", but with different levels of technology and sugar. This is in contrast to "using classic OS threads and mutexes and semaphores" where you think in terms of active threads and the coordination and scheduling between them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I can more easily see the difference between async and event based programming. It is just that I saw those used together more often than not that I confused the two for being one.

Comment: The more I thought about this, the more I seem to lose the difference between async and blocking. The use cases I have in mind are creating a promise then doing multiple `then`s on the future from it. In the case of blocking threads, it is just a context switch. Given enough time spent active, the context switch will not be noticeable. While on the other hand, if it is checking if the result is ready periodically, then the last paragraph wouldn't apply. Am I missing something? I'm not saying async is useless, just that it has more limited uses than what I hear about.

Comment: @Incomputable The way I understand it is that things like `async` and `await` or promise `then` callbacks builds upon low-level thread coordination the way loops build on low-level gotos. They translate in a structured, consistent way that is more limited and with more overhead, but are ultimately more predictable and quick to use. When I write `getValue().then(useValue)`, I can assume that code will execute in that order as time progresses, albeit with a time disconnect. Notably the *thread* could run other code in the meantime - why should I care!

Comment: A great example of how asynchrony is a human-understandable approach: When the waiter tells the cook that table 5 wants a lasagna; does the waiter then stand still until they receive that lasagna for table 5? No. They go and do something else, and _when the lasagna is returned_, they come back round to pick it up and finish the order for table 5.

Answer (score 10):

Fundamentally the answer comes down to the fact that threads are not free.  There is overhead associated with each thread.  I found [this article](https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/why-too-many-threads-hurts-performance-and-what-to-do-about-it/) which is written by former Intel Engineer Arch D. Robison who explains this using the TBB scheduler, which is what I think you mentioned you have familiarity with.

> The impact of having too many threads comes in two ways. First, partitioning a fixed amount of work among too many threads gives each thread too little work that the overhead of starting and terminating threads swamps the useful work. Second, having too many threads running incurs overhead from the way they share finite hardware resources.

Most significantly for this discussion, the cost of switching can be very significant.  In our discussion, you mentioned a thread switching time of 10 microseconds.  If we assume that's correct for the moment, consider that on a 1GHz machine (e.g. an Athlon circa 2000), that's 10,000 clock cycles.  Robison explains part of why this is so costly:

> Modern processors rely heavily on cache memory, which can be about 10 to 100 times faster than main memory. Accesses that hit in cache are not only much faster; they also consume no bandwidth from the memory bus. Caches are fast, but finite. When the cache is full, a processor must evict data from the cache to make room for new data. Typically, the choice for eviction is the least recently used data, which is typically data from an earlier time slice. Thus software threads tend to evict each other’s data,

Moreover:

> On Linux, starting and terminating an Intel® TBB task is about 18 times faster than starting and terminating a thread. On Windows, the ratio is more than 100.

Effectively, these higher-level abstractions are able to more efficiently manage the work in order to avoid all the overhead of thread switching.  I think one thing about this that you need to consider is that this probably doesn't matter much if you are running one heavyweight process on a machine.  But these improvements are designed to support things running at scale.  Once you hit a certain number of threads on a given machine, it will spend more time on switching thread contexts than it is executing the program logic.  By eliminating this thread-switching overhead, I can get more productive work done on the same hardware.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I will delete my question because I gained a lot of insight into what's going on and how to write a much more insightful question. Sorry that this answer will probably go to waste (my new question will refute each and every point in this answer, so if you want to read about it, stay tuned, probably next week). Well, it seems like I cannot delete it. But either way, I would like to make great amendments to it. I guess I should ask mods for that.

Comment: @Incomputable I don't see any reason to delete this.  If you have this question, someone else will surely have it too.  You can ask another question regardless.

Comment: in asynchronous model worker threads "manually" switch contexts much more often than in thread-per-request/thread-per-connection, so in asynchronous model there are way more cache misses and invalidations, thus the facts you pointed are **against** the asynchronous model. Furthermore, there's nothing that stops us from maintaining a thread-pool in thread-per-request/connection model as well to avoid frequent thread creation/destruction: just the maximum limit should be much bigger.

Comment: @morgwai Can you provide some docs/evidence of increased cache misses?

Comment: I would be honestly astonished if a single thread running coroutines had more cache misses than multiple threads context-switching. The coroutines would have to be as heavy-weight as a thread execution context for this to seem plausible. I guess there are corner cases like each coroutine fills L1 and they never share any memory ...

Comment: @Useless That's my thinking and it would contradict a lot of what I've read from seemingly reliable sources.  The other thing is that IO requests wouldn't seem to have a lot of state to store.

Comment: @JimmyJames as you brought this, I've put more thinking into this and have realized that in both models context switching  happens almost exclusively at points where blocking/asynchronous calls are issued. In both cases there will be 100% cache miss when the reply data arrives and usually 100% cache hit elsewhere as discussed in comments to my answer. So my current thinking is that these models are roughly equivalent in terms of cache hit ratio. Thanks for your comments that helped me realize this! :)

Comment: If you have a lot of processing to do when a packet arrives, most of that processing will presumably be "steady state" and we can assume the cache behaviour is no different under either system. If you have only a little processing to do when a packet arrives, then the important concern is the state transition itself. If you have a single thread, at least its stack and execution context will always be hot. With many threads, they almost never will be. So, it depends entirely on how long your steady state runs and your latency requirements.

Answer (score 8):

A lot of event driven programming is because the applications are event driven. You're running code to handle a button click, or a received packet, or a timer expiring. That sort of code is actually more awkward to write in a synchronous style. While you are correct that long-running CPU-bound synchronous code should get its own thread instead of manually specifying suspend points, *most* code is relatively short-lived IO-bound event handlers.

In my opinion, another reason for the growth of async programming is the growth of JavaScript programming. JavaScript is single-threaded, so you need async to do any sort of concurrency, and people looked for better and better patterns to do so, borrowing and lending good ideas between other languages.

Another reason is threads are much heavier than fibers. You might ask why we don't just create lighter weight threads. As [this great article](https://typelevel.org/blog/2021/02/21/fibers-fast-mkay.html) explains, one big reason is that threads are where your call stack is, and the garbage collector needs to be aware of the call stack in order to determine what memory is reachable. This tracking adds per-thread overhead. Likewise at the OS level for things like swapping.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is there a shift towards asynchronous and event driven programming?

My explanation would be that the tooling have become better. While many operating systems have had support for asynchronous IO for a long time, it has often been difficult to use effectively. Many modern languages feature some form of easy to use coroutine/async/await that lowers the barrier to entry.

This kind of programming is well suited when doing lots of IO, and this has increased in importance as as processors have become faster, while IO latency has not improved as much. Just blocking the thread while doing IO is not a great solution since UI programs would freeze while the UI thread blocks, and server programs would have a higher overhead due to all the blocked threads.

This does not mean that regular thread based programming is not relevant. I would consider the techniques complementary. When doing CPU intensive stuff you obviously need threads to do the processing.

Comment: "When doing CPU intensive stuff *that's embarrassingly parallel*" There are still workloads that don't thread well

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! Unfortunately I will probably delete it because I gained a lot more understanding on the subject that provide much stronger arguments against event based programming. Sorry.

Comment: @Incomputable Why don't you submit an answer with your findings?

Comment: @VincentSavard, if the question will avoid close/reopen battles, then I will do that. I didn't think of this, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Caleth Or if responsiveness should be assured.

Answer (score 4):

IME you're arguing from a false premise.

Your "classic" *threads with blocking I/O* model was popularized by Java, which was the first widely-used language to have standardized built-in thread support, and which did not initially support non-blocking I/O at all. Threaded blocking I/O was the *only* form of (de)multiplexing it supported.

I was already writing C++ code on UNIX using the traditional select/poll non-blocking reactor style while Java was gaining popularity, and I saw the explosion of Java documentation & tutorials - together with similar-enough syntax - encourage people to try the same style in C++. From my perspective this was an aberration, caused entirely by the popularity of the newer language and the particular order in which features were added.

The reactor-style approach is more work, because you have to manually track lots of state that would otherwise exist as local variables in an almost-alway-blocked thread. However, it has always been vastly more efficient for I/O bound systems. When Java eventually got NIO, it became possible to do efficient (de)multiplexing in the same style there as well.

The newer async event-based style essentially provides better language support for this, removing the need for most custom callback classes and manually managing what was effectively coroutine state.

---

NB. I'm not really addressing async/await style in this answer, just the underlying assumption about multi-threaded blocking I/O versus single threaded non-blocking I/O. The fact that the latter is simplified by using coroutines doesn't mean it needs an async thread pool - except, perhaps, for spinning off long-running operations so it can get back to I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Verifying lack of deadlocks is easier with async driven code than with sync blocking code. In a synchronous system with multiple threads and multiple mutexes, how does one verify correctness?  There is manual code inspection; however, this cannot be automated. Subsequent code changes may cause race conditions and deadlocks. Async structures are not dependent on other threads being correct and thus are easier to test and verify with an automated test.

Comment: Async code opens another problem then: the async operation could get preempted in the middle of an update, then another coroutine/fiber/whatever wants to read from that object. Async/blocking threading do not solve sharing problem, but async is superior in cases when context switch becomes noticable as incase of IO operations. Blocking threading, on the other hand, is usually a lot more efficient in terms of battery usage and stuff, because it sleeps.

Comment: @Incomputable While anync is not free from issues, consider this article called the ['Top 20 C++ multithreading mistakes and how to avoid them'](https://www.acodersjourney.com/top-20-cplusplus-multithreading-mistakes/)  Note that it's just the Top 20!  There are so many ways you can get it wrong.  More crucially (IMO) there's really no way to test multi-threaded code exhaustively.  Even if it works in testing on one system (hard enough) there are effectively unlimited scenarios.  Even if you could test them all, there still could be bugs that will appear on other hardware.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problems with asynchronous approach is that it's difficult to read (callback hell) and error prone (deadlocks, race conditions, etc) unless advanced language support is available. One example is async/await in C# or Node that makes the request processing code look "linear" and similar to thread-per-request/thread-per-connection.
Asynchronous approach may also be a bit slower due to synchronization overhead. However in case of IO-bound applications this is almost always insignificant.

OTOH, the main problem with thread-per-request/thread-per-connection is (used to be) that for services with many users, a lot of threads need to be created. Depending on specific hardware+OS platform it may not be feasible (more on that later).

**update:** I used to think also that asynchronous approach results in more cache misses, but thanks to the discussion in this thread exactly, I've realized that it's the same for both asynchronous and thread-per-request/thread-per-connection models. In both models context switching happens almost exclusively at points where async/blocking calls are issued. When responses to these calls return, there will be 100% cache miss in both models. Finally in both models there will be almost 100% success cache hit during execution of  synchronous non-blocking code: as most requests are waiting for their async/blocking calls to return, they don't compete for cache with the very few remaining active.

**NOW SOME HISTORY BACKGROUND:**

Before the mobile revolution, this was rarely a problem: very few internet services ever experienced more than 100 concurrent requests, so for almost everyone except Google, Yahoo, AOL etc, thread-per-request/thread-per-connection model was sufficient. Things changed drastically in late 2000s and within just few years roughly 50% population of the developed world started to access internet services dozens-hundreds of times a day. Suddenly, even moderately popular services started to have hundreds of concurrent requests during peak hours.
This also happened to be roughly the same time when shared server hosting services became cheap and popular and every hosting provider was copying Google's approach to data-center design: replace a few very expensive main-frames with hundreds of cheap, easily replaceable, almost-consumer-grade machines (early days Google clusters were built from decommissioned office PCs). Google claimed that this approach was more cost effective and fault tolerant: this was true, but as Google's code-base was a very tightly guarded secret at that time, they didn't mention that it comes with another cost...

**LIMIT OF THREAD NUMBER ON 32BIT HARDWARE:**

Most of the hardware at that time, except that main-frames that ppl were migrating away from, was still 32bit (64bit CPUs like AMD's Opterons were available, but still waaay more expensive). This limits virtual memory address space to 4GB (2^32) and usually a bit over 3GB is available to user space.
Now on most platforms, virtual address space (**not** the actual physical memory) containing thread's stack needs to be allocated right away when the thread is created and cannot be later expanded or switched. As some programs may be using deep, non-tail recursions, the default initial stack virtual address space is big on most platforms: on Linux it's 2MB (RHEL even had some variants with 10MB).
Assuming even 0 heap-memory usage, this allows to create 3GB/2MB=1500 threads on 1 machine (and only 300 if stack address space is 10MB). Given standard average heap usage, virtual memory bounds were usually reached with about 500-900 concurrent requests.
For more info see [this excellent aricle](https://akkadia.org/drepper/thread-number-stacks.html) by Ulrich Drepper.

**TOWARDS ASYNC MODEL:**

The solution (and the cost that Google didn't mention before) was exactly a switch to the asynchronous server model: using small fixed pool of threads that switch requests whenever the current one is performing some blocking operation. This allowed to handle even 10_000 concurrent requests on the same machines that were previously melting at not even 1000 due to the problems described above. Everyone was super excited and a trend followed: we got async/await in F# in 2007, async support in Java Servlets in 2009, async/await in C# in 2011 and so on...
"*And for the time it was good*"

**MIGRATION TO 64BIT HARDWARE:**

Sometime in early 2010s AFAIR, 64bit CPUs became cheap enough to replace all 32bit ones, at least on servers. 64bit address space is huUUUuge: even with 10MB stack address space allocation, it's enough for more than about 1T (trillion) threads, so basically it's not a concern for the time being.

**CONCLUSIONS:**

So why is asynchronous style still so popular? There are some cases when it definitely is still useful:

- probably for processing events on some IoT or embedded devices that still may be using 32bit CPUs.
- it may be more convenient GUI event handling or, to that matter, any other situation with multiple independent events that result in modification of some common state. Since it is necessary to properly synchronize access to the common state anyway, most of the disadvantages of asynchronous model will also affect thread-per-request/connection model anyway.

However, for standard **IO-bound** server programming (if your service fetches data from a DB or communicates with a non-local dependent micro-service) with request-response processing (like HTTP or some RPC), that is **mostly** stateless (there is little data exchange and synchronization between separate requests), I don't think that asynchronous model is much useful anymore. IMO it should be avoided in languages that don't have good support for async programming (like Java or C++) unless indeed beneficial.
Of course there's nothing wrong with using it with languages that for example have async/await mechanism, like C# or Node. In fact, .net-core's kestrel server is asynchronous by design and its thread-pool's size is equal to the number available CPU cores. Node used to be single-threaded for long time.

Nevertheless, for reasons that I don't exactly understand, async model is still quite popular in Java in cases where it doesn't bring any value any more (like servlets fetching data from a DB). I *suppose* that it may be a matter of perpetuated thinking that maintaining a pool of several thousands threads is still very expensive, which is not true anymore.
For example Jetty on Linux can easily scale up to 32k threads without any tuning on a typical modern Linux *laptop* (see [this article](https://webtide.com/do-looms-claims-stack-up-part-1)). For most apps and typical server hardware, 32k thread limit significantly exceeds  number of concurrent requests that a machine can squeeze due to physical memory limit needed to fit all requests' data on the server's heap.

Comment: If you have enough threads they only fit in virtual memory with a 64-bit address space, they're practically guaranteed never to be in cache when they wake up. This might be absolutely fine for many use cases, but for many others it's completely unacceptable. I'm pretty sure that having different non-functional requirements than you does not make me a chimpanzee.

Comment: @Useless first, please don't take it personally ;-) the experiment was actually projected towards corporate rules and authors were pointing that humans often fall a victim of such bias as well. I myself have fallen into it few times at least. Now for the memory: current machines don't have enough physical RAM to handle enough requests to fill virtual address space. The biggest successful squeeze per machine in real life service I've seen was about 10_000. Generally the amount of cache should be proportional to the amount of RAM, that's why putting 256GB RAM into a main-board with small...

Comment: I'm not upset about the simian simile, just pointing out that my performance constraints are real, even though they're different to yours.

Comment: @Useless [continuing] ...amount of cache is often pointless. However, for typical DB-bound internet services, most threads in thread-per-request/connection model sleep most of the time waiting for data from the DB. The small percentage of active threads use cache quite efficiently then. When data comes from the DB, there's a huge cache miss for the given thread, but it's a insignificant comparing to the time spent waiting for the DB.

Comment: @Useless I've added emphasized note that my thinking was regard DB-bound services. Indeed, for pure CPU bound services, asynchronous model may be better, but I don't have enough experience to say. Thanks for pointing!  :)

Comment: "When data comes from the DB, there's a huge cache miss for the given thread, but it's a insignificant comparing to the time spent waiting for the DB."  I think follow this reasoning but what about the scenario where almost every thread is waiting on IO?  That is, you have a constant flow of threads starting to wait and others getting their responses.   It would seem to me that you would have near 100% cache misses pretty much all the time.

Comment: @JimmyJames you are correct: there would be indeed 100% cache miss rate right after the arrival of the data. But OTOH, you would have almost 100% cache hit rate after that, during _processing_ of this data as very few threads are competing for the cache because majority is sleeping waiting for their data arrival. Similarly, if request parameter data is not big (which is most commonly the case, except of file uploads, etc) you would have almost 100% during request parameter processing before sending your request to the DB (or any other non-local micro-service).

Comment: "very few threads are competing for the cache because majority is sleeping waiting for their data arrival." Correct me if I am wrong here but I think we can assume that this kind of thing is the same for both the thread and async model (literally: you seem to have agreed as I was writing this :-)  If most of my threads are sleeping, most of my coroutines would be sleeping.  The question, it seems is what is the overhead for a minimal IO waiting thread?  I mean the request parameters are the same but what would the thread add to that (if anything) outside of the virtual memory? (cont)

Comment: (cont) I started reading the article you linked to and I found this one too which seems to address the same kind of questions: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/measuring-context-switching-and-memory-overheads-for-linux-threads/

Comment: @JimmyJames yes :) I've just updated my answer regarding the cache hits. Thanks again for the fruitful discussion!

Comment: Yes, this has been very informative.  My belief/argument is that the push has been around scalability.  The idea being that an (IO bound) webserver can handle more concurrent requests using async requests.  Your points have made me question some of my assumptions around this which is great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131546/discussion-between-jimmyjames-and-morgwai).

Answer (score 0):

Just answering the "asynchronous" part of your question

Here are some technical reasons why "asynchronous" programming is advancing

- In Android you must handle web-service-Requests / downloads in a seperate background-threads to avoid a frozen userinterface (or to avoid that android kills your app because it is not responding)
- Tools/Libraries makes it very easy and memory efficient to implement asynchronous

  - Javascript with [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) makes async programming easy. Running js code on a [NodeJS Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) makes executing the promises very efficient.
  - In Java8 and later there is the [CompletableFuture API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) that can be used similar to js promises,
- In scallable, parallel, distributed computing of big data there is the programming model [Map Reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) that requires "asynchronous" programming